# combine multiple pdf plots into one file

Tags: r

I am trying to merge multiple pdf plots into one master pdf file.

Example:

Input: I have three pdf files: "1.pdf", "2.pdf", and "3.pdf"

Output: How to combine these three plots into one file called "combine.pdf"

I tried using pdf(), and pdftk(), but not successful yet, may be I am missing something simply. Thought to request for help. Greatly appreciate any response.

Comment: You can't use a pdf file as an input for `R`, you need a `pdf` editor for that.

Comment: `pdftk 1.pdf 2.pdf... output output.pdf`, see http://www.accesspdf.com/pdftk/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `sweave/knitr` to get more flexibility and merge easily new plots ,old ones and texts:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\begin{document}
 this my plot 1:    % write some texts here
\includepdf{1.pdf} 
 this my plot 2:
\includepdf{2.pdf} 
 this my plot 3:
\includepdf{3.pdf} 
 this my plot 4:
\includepdf{4.pdf} 
 a new plot:
<<echo=FALSE>>=         % chunk for new plots
x <- rnorm(100)
hist(x)
@
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8):

I asked a similar question a while back and Ananda Mahto generously provide time and code to help make a [github package](https://github.com/trinker/plotflow) that can combine multiple plots of different sizes.  I use it in my workflow a bit but have no plans to push it to CRAN but you can download it with the `devtools` package.  Note that you have to have [ghostscript](http://www.ghostscript.com/) installed and on your path for this to work:

**## Getting the plotflow github package:**

```
library(devtools)
install_github("plotflow", "trinker")
library(plotflow)
```

**## 2 Examples using the package to merge multiple pdfs**

```
## Example 1
merge_pdf(3, file = "foo.pdf", widths = c(7, 7, 10), heights = c(6, 10, 7))
plot(1:10)
plot(1:10, pch=19)
plot(1:10, col="red", pch=19)

## Example 2
library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(factor(cyl), mpg)) + geom_boxplot()
merge_pdf(2, file = "bar.pdf", widths = c(7, 10), heights = c(6, 10))
plot(1:10)
print(p)
```

***Note*** that if you already have the pdfs you may want to look at the [plotflow:::mergePDF](https://github.com/trinker/plotflow/blob/master/R/mergePDF.R) function.

Answer (score 0):

Using the command line prompt in Linux, I found this works, if you are in the same directory and the .pdf files are in the order you want them in the final pdf doc.

gs -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -q -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=Chart_Pak.pdf *.pdf

Answer (score 0):

include below code into PHP script

```
shell_exec("gs -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dPDFFitPage -sPAPERSIZE=a4 -dFIXEDMEDIA -sOUTPUTFILE= abc.pdf xyz.pdf");
```