# Change PDF size when it is open

Tags: r, pdf, graphics, plot, ggplot2

We can open a pdf file with custom width and height using `pdf(file="foo.pdf",width=10,height=20)` command for example.

But I want make a Pdf file containing several charts in different pages. Some of my charts need larger page dimensions, some need smaller (having the same font size for all). So far I have done like this:

```
pdf("foo.pdf", width=10,height=20)
#Draw figure 1
dev.off()

pdf("bar.pdf", width=5,height=5)
#Draw figure 2 
dev.off()
```

Is there anyway that I have all plots in a single PDF file, with different dimensions for every page?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18069273/1412059