# Printing long code block R markdown pdf

Tags: r, r-markdown, miktex

I am trying to print a long code, highlighted with R syntax, at the end of my thesis, written in R markdown. I am knitting to pdf. I receive the error: `! Dimension too large`.

I am copy pasting my code into the document:

```` ```R
Pasted code
``` ````

I was wondering if there is a way to avoid the error when printing my code in R markdown.

Comment: Have you tried to cut your code in multiples chunks?

Comment: That would probably work, but would be very tedious, as it's a very long code. It's my last resort!

Comment: In R-studio you could compile a report using `rmarkdown::render("yourCode.R", "pdf_document")` After that combine thesis and code pdfs considering [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26846704/6574038) answer,